# Export Sonar dashboards from database/plugins

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am new to sonar administration.

I have several team wise dashboards created. Each of the sonar dashboards have multiple unit test coverage widgets. My requirement is that I need a mechanism to extract the code coverage % from these widgets and save it in an excel/csv. I was thinking about the following approaches:

1. Export the dashboards using plugins (If possible)?
2. Does the sonar database store these dashboards? If yes then is there a way we can query it.

Answer (score 0):

The best and recommended way to extract data from SonarQube to generate such kind of excel/csv file is to use the Web Service API that will allow you to query whatever you want from SonarQube.

Please read the [WS API documentation](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/old-web-service-api.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Is there an example which I can refer to?